# How to selectively change font style (e.g. make italics, etc) in TextView in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitextview

I have few lines of text in TextView.

I want to apply italics to some of these lines (not all).

It is not possible for me to us seperate textviews in this particular case.

How can I make the text italics in that case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible in that case. Use `UIWebview` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using NSAttributed strings in the text view.